# Not getting return values in $getJSON object

Tags: javascript, php, json

Javascript:

```
$.getJSON("path", function(data){alert(data.name)})
```

Guys in this line "data" is not working as an object. name is unrecognizable here. 
I am sending multiple outputs in php using json_encode() function but not able to get those values in javascript file.

PHP Code:

```
$book = array("name"=>"bob", "num"=>1);

echo json_encode($book);
```

Comment: It's `$.getJSON()` -> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: Sorry, It is included in my code.. I mistyped here.

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Are you sure your _`path`_ is correct?